# Python: Why is DictWriter writing 'NULL' bytes?

Tags: python, dictionary, null, python-2.6

```
class WhatsGoingOn:
    def __init__(self, filename, fieldNames, maxLines):
        self.file_to_write = filename
        self.fieldNames = fieldNames'
        self.maxLines = maxLines

        # Open the file for reading and writing. Create it if it doesn't exist, 
        #  and truncate it if it does.
        self.file = open(self.file_to_write, 'w+b')
        self.csvReader = csv.DictReader(self.file, fieldnames=self.fieldNames)
        self.csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(self.file, fieldnames=self.fieldNames, extrasaction='ignore')

    def looper(self):
        # Infinitly (don't worry about that - this is a daemon), 
        #  write to the file. When a certain number of lines have been written, 
        #  read the file and then truncate it.
        try:
            numRowsWritten = 0
            while True:
                # Nevermind what's being written
                self.csvWriter.writerow({'name_of_field_0': str(numRowsWritten ), 'name_of_field_1': str(numRowsWritten )})
                numRowsWritten  += 1

                if numRowsWritten  >= self.maxLines:
                    # Iterate through each row of the file
                    self.file.seek(0)

                    # This only works the first time...
                    for row in self.csvReader:
                        print row['name_of_field']

                    # Truncate the file, and restart the 
                    self.file.truncate(0)
                    numRowsWritten  = 0

        except Exception as e:
            print 'Exception!: {0}'.format(e)
            self.file.close()
```

**Output:** `Exception!: line contains NULL byte`

The second time the `for row in self.csvReader:` line gets hit, the exception gets thrown, and when I look at the file, the file does indeed have a whole bunch of NULL bytes at the start. Apparently, after the file got truncated, the DictWriter wrote a whole bunch of NULL bytes (or at least that's my assumption). **How do I prevent NULL bytes from being written to my file?**

Comment: I guess `if i >= self.maxLines` is within `while True` loop. And, can you please correct the line print row['name_of_field]. The string is not terminated.

Comment: My guess would be that the Reader is caching the position it previously read from, rather than trusting the file position (which you modified with `seek(0)`. Since it's trying to read from off the end of the file, it gets bogus data.

Comment: It's definitely reading from the beginning of the file since it tells me that it is reading NULL bytes and that there are, in fact, NULL bytes at the beginning of `file` which weren't there the first time the condition `if numRowsWritten  >= self.maxLines:` is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, by truncating the file, you mess up some internal state of the writer. Instead of truncating, close and re-open the file (mode `w+b` truncates), then re-initialize the `csvReader` and `csvWriter`.

Comment: That works, thanks. I wonder why truncate is messing things up though.